# How to test a public method that calls a private method with a mocked object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5, powermockito

I am testing a class "DataSource" that extends another class "ExtendedDataSource". The method that I am testing in the "DataSource" class is calling another protected method in the "ExtendedDataSource" class.

```java
class DataSource extends ExtendedDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Connection setup(Properties props) {
        Connection connection = super.getConnection(props);
        return connection;
    }
}

class ExtendedDataSource extends AbstractSource {

    @Override
    protected Connection getConnection(Properties props) {
        // here an user is retrieved from an abstract class that this class inherits
        // In this line I am getting an exception IllegalStateException--"user not set"
        String user = getUser();

        // Does something with props
        
        // Calls another protected method with the props as argument
        anothermethod(props); 
    }

    protected anothermethod(Properties props){
        //call another method that will do something with props 
    }
}

    public abstract class AbstractSource extends AnotherAbstractClass{
    
    public String getUser() {
        //the user as string
        return user;
    }
}
```

> The test for the DataSource class is as follows :-

```java
public class DataSourceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Mock
    properties props;

    @Test
    public void datatest() {

        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();

        dataSource.getConnection(props);

    }

}
```

How should I get over this situation? Should I also mock the Abstract class? But in this way do I have to mok all the classes?

Comment: You already have a mocked `DataSource`. Just mock the `getUser` implementation from there.

Comment: getUser implementation is in an abstract class that this class inherits. The abstract class is again inheriting another Abstract class. So like this do I need to mock all the abstract classes what is associated with the method?

Comment: What? Your `DataSource` *is* an instance of those classes. You don't mock classes, you mock instances.

Comment: @Jon - what do you mean by moccking the getUser() implementation? In the AbstractSource it only returns "return this.user;". I did the following--

Mock
String User;
 
AbstractSource abs=Mockito.mock(AbstractSource.class);
when(abs.getUser).thenReturn(user);

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing the `DataSource` class, you're not supposed to mock it. Usually you mock the dependencies of the class. The purpose is bringing the class you want to test to some ***state*** by injecting mocks of its dependencies, and then asserting the return values of its methods given the provided ***state***. For example, if the constructor of `DataSource` looks like this:

```
public DataSource(Object o) {

    this.o = o;
}
```

Then you're supposed to mock `o` and then create an instance of `DataSource` with this mocked `o`. The ***test*** now is calling `dataSource.setup(...)`, given the state that you mocked:

```
Object mock = Mockito.mock(Object.class);
DataSource dataSource = new DataSource(mock);
Assert.assertNotNull(dataSource.setup(...));
```

**Now to go to your case** - the issue that you're describing is exactly why when possible, I prefer composition over inheritance. My suggestion is that `DataSource` will get `ExtendedDataSource` (consider renaming it) in its constructor instead of extending it:

```
public DataSource(ExtendedDataSource extendedDataSource) {

    this.extendedDataSource = extendedDataSource;
}
```

Now you can mock `ExtendedDataSource` and setup some return value to `ExtendedDataSource.getConnection`, then create an instance of `DataSource` and pass the mock in the constructor, and assert the behavior of `DataSource` as you wanted:

```
ExtendedDataSource extendedDataSource = Mockito.mock(ExtendedDataSource.class);
Mockito.when(extendedDataSource.getConnection(...)).thenReturn(...);
DataSource dataSource = new DataSource(extendedDataSource);
Assert.assertNotNull(dataSource.setup(...));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the valuable inputs! I understand that when the object is injected to the constructor it becomes easier to test. I have mocked the props object and sent it as a parameter. The problem is with the setUrl() function. It is in an abstract class and giving IllegalStateException. But I have already mocked the props and sent it as an argument.

Comment: I can't see `setUrl` in your post, but anyway - it sounds to me that `DataSource` is calling `setUrl`. Once again - mocking DataSource or any of its parent classes won't help you, since eventually you need to test a concrete instance of DataSource, so my recommendation - replace inheritance with composition, mock the abstract class and pass it to `DataSource` in the constructor, and then - test easily.

Comment: Sorry it is not setUrl rather getUser() which is in an abstract class. Furthermore, I cannot call extendedDataSource.getConnection() as the getConnection method is protected and cannot be called like that.